# What happens when request comes to Tomcat server?

Tags: java, tomcat

When request comes to Tomcat server, it checks the web.xml and based on url-mapping, Request will be redirected. This is okay if Tomcat server has only one application deployed in it.

But what happens when Tomcat server has more than one application deployed in it? When REQUEST comes to Tomcat server, how it knows which application it has to invoke? Someone told me there is a file called server.xml (or something like that) where we provide some url-mapping to each and every application that we deploy in server. Based on that Tomcat redirects the Request to that particular application web.xml.

Can someone please let me know the flow of Request processing?

Comment: you don't need to change server.xml, just deploy each application in it's folder, inside `webapps` directory at tomcat, some times you need something like `alias` or `virtualhost` you may need to work on `server.xml` otherwise, no need, that's what i know

Comment: p.s: the folder name used in `webapps` will be part of the request url, ex: `http://server-address/app1/index.jsp` or `http://server-address/app2/index.jsp` .. etc

Comment: Note that `http://yoursever/someapplication/` is mapped to an application  named `someapplication`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) You just need to place your war files into Tomcat's webapps folder.
2) Tomcat expands each war file into a folder and automatically deploys all the war files.
3) Once the applications are up, based on the request url defined in deployment descriptor, the request is directed to a particular application.

Comment: This is true.  I would add that it is possible to define a default application that answers to "/" rather than /<name_of_application>, but this requires additional configuration and in my experience, most programmers tend to prefer not to set it entirely especially with multiple applications.

Comment: True, while most applications don't need to be unpacked, to be deployed (2 is optional). This often makes developers storing files in the unpacked folders, i.e. uploads, which will than be deleted, once the the application is redeployed.